# Routing table interpretation

Tags: networking, router, routing

I found this address in my computer's routing table:

> 255.255.255.255/32

What is it?

Answer (score 3):

It is a special reserved IPv4 Limited Broadcasts address reserved for the loop back address -- such as 127.0.0.1 and the host IP address. That being said, the way it is written it is technically considered a netmask with only one host. As you might know that there can't be an network with just one host. Hints the reason it is reserved as the broadcast address of the loop back address. Here Some more information, however limited, can be found at this Microsoft Social Answer [thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/d6dd3fd3-fa6a-4df8-be07-9b36d0470870).